# Javascript function to check a box based on value of select option

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a javascript function, which changes a select option to 1 if a checkbox is checked.  What I can't seem to figure out, is how to automatically check the box if the user fails to tick the checkbox and just chooses a value (other than 0) from the select dropdown.  The script has ID's and names that are generated with php array values.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

```
function quantityChangeHandler(source) {
    var qtyElem = document.getElementById(source.getAttribute('rel'));
    if (source.checked) {
        if (qtyElem.value == 0)
            qtyElem.value = 1;
        }
    else 
            qtyElem.value = 0;
}

<input type="checkbox" onclick="quantityChangeHandler(this)" 
name="prodid[<?php echo $prodid;?>][]" rel="prodqty_<?php echo $prodid . '_' . $contactid; ?>" 
value="<?php echo $contactid; ?>" /><br />

Qty
<select id="prodqty_<?php echo $prodid . '_' . $contactid; ?>"
name="prodqty[<?php echo $prodid; ?>][<?php echo $contactid; ?>]">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a similar handler and `rel` attribute to the `select` tag, and *set* `source.checked` based on the value of the `select` element.

Add this to your Javascript:

```
function selectChangeHandler(source) {
    var checkboxElem = document.getElementById(source.getAttribute('rel'));
    checkboxElem.checked = source.value != 0;
}
```

Example changes to HTML:

```
<input id="checkbox_0" ... />
...
<select ... rel="checkbox_0" onchange="selectChangeHandler(this)">
...
```

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2YG9/)

Comment: Wow - what a quick response!  Thank you so much.  For some reason, I just couldn't see it, and you saved my sanity.  Thank you again.

Comment: This answer (and thank you for the JSFiddle example) worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding manually trigger the checkbox selection is by triggering the click event.

say you checkbox id = "mychkbox"

then using the jquery you can do by $('#mychkbox').trigger('click');

this makes the check box selected selected.

and your check condition for if checkbox is selected or not.